# css - relative header and sticky footer, dynamic content, unknown height, all in a container with responsive width?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, sticky-footer

Am working on a relative header and sticky footer, with dynamically loaded content (sometimes an empty div (unknown height) hence height: 100vh;), all within a responsive container that adjusts to the width of the device (width: 100vw;) up to a max-width of 350px.

From there, some content loads dynamically above the header and should push down the header and the content, but should keep the sticky footer in place.  The dynamic content, when it overflows, should scroll out below the header and above the footer because both are semi-transparent.

Have tried all sorts of combinations of (relative and absolute)..here's the closest one, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/9U2CU/5/.. but this combination guesses the percentage height of the dynamic content, and the content that appears is incorrectly formatted in scope and does not push down the dynamic-content because of the absolute positioning!?

What adjustments need to be made to the CSS to account for the specs?

HTML

```
<div id="view">

    <div id="appear" style="display:none;">Content that appears</div>

    <div id="header">Some Buttons</div>
    <div id="dynamic-content"></div>
    <div id="footer">Some Buttons</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#view {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 350px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
#dynamic-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #999;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on("click", "#header", function () {
    $('#appear').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: what was the question?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what css will keep everything in place? a header that moves only when the #appear toggles, dynamic content that scrolls behind the header and the footer, all in a container that responds to the width of the device up to 350px, and is full-height of the device..(corrected details)

Comment: I've read a couple of times your question and I have frankly no clue what you're after... first you state in your title *"css - relative header and sticky footer"* and than suddenly *A"m working on a fixed header+footer,..."* `fixed` ? Also what kind of page should have 350px max width? This is a sidebar widget? (asking just out of curiosity.)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Pardon the inconsistencies.. Here's a closer example http://jsfiddle.net/9U2CU/5/, but this combination guesses the percentage height of the dynamic content, and the content that appears is incorrectly formatted in scope and does not push down the dynamic-content because of the absolute positioning

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan many thanks for taking a look at this

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan All accurate.. content scrolls behind the fixed footer and stationary header, which only moves when the panel slidesDown from the top (onClick of a button in the header)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan and this is all contained in a panel that is full width of the device up to 350px, and is full height of the device/page

Comment: Check out Twitter Bootstrap's sticky footer for some inspiration, it works by having the body content in a wrap: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer-navbar.html

Comment: position: fixed, not that you are using it, is not to be trusted IOS, IPAD will work unexpectedly at least on zoom

Comment: @BrianOgden almost every other mobile has it's issues with FIXED elements. ;) Anyway the demo you provided seems exactly the opposite of what the OP wants :) AFAIHU footer should be `fixed` and `header` .. dunno frankly :)

Comment: @BrianOgden yeh, would prefer avoiding position: fixed for the reasons mentioned.. and it seems like there's a creative solution here for the stationary elements working with the dynamic elements..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/negin/9/edit)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="view">
  <div id="appear"> Content that appears </div>
  <div id="header"> Header </div>
  <div id="content"> <h1>Content</h1> <p>Lorem ipsum...</p> </div>
  <div id="footer"> Footer </div>
</div>
```

**CSS3:**
 using `calc()` which currently has a very good xBrowser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

```
#view {
  overflow: hidden;           /* NO SCROLLBARS */
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000;
  color:#fff;

  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
}
#appear{
  display:none;
}
#header,
#footer {
  height: 44px;               /* note this */
  background-color: #555;
}
#content {
  overflow-y: scroll;         /* SCROLLBARS !!!*/
  height: calc(100% - 88px);  /* 44+44 = 88px */
}
```

and finally
**jQuery:**

```
$("#view").on("click", "#header", function () {
  var $appear = $('#appear');
  var io = this.io ^= 1; // Toggler

  $appear.show();               // Temporarily show
  var animH = $appear.height(); // Get height and
  if(io) $appear.hide();        // fast hide.
  $appear.slideToggle();        // Now do it with animation

  $('#content').animate({       // Animate content height
      height: (io?"-=":"+=")+animH
    },{
      step: function() {
        $(this).css("overflow-y", "scroll");
      },
      complete : function(){
        var h = 88 + (io?animH:0); // header+footer = 88px
        $(this).css({height: "calc(100% - "+ h +"px)"});
      }
   });
});
```

To explain the beauty above:
the trick is to set a fixed height to header and to Footer,
than using `calc(100% - 88px)` for the scrollable content you get the needed space.

On jQuery animate you just quickly get the Appearing Top content height and apply it to the `calc()` magic in jQuery.

Comment: truly grateful, really incredible

Comment: @StackThis thanks! :) you're welcome! The only possible issue with the code above is that currently (as it is right now) Header and Footer need a fixed height, but for a mobile design I hope it's not a big deal cause usually header and footer do not change in height (most of the time :D ).

Comment: This is perfect! The header and footer have set heights.. Very inspiring code!!

Comment: @StackThis I've tested this on 2 Androids (4,3 and 2.2), works only in Chrome and Firefox mobile browsers... Default Browsers have some issues probably fixable if you use `meta` for device and some additional effort. I mean the issues are that the whole page is scrollable. Nothing that bad. Firefox and Chrome are OK

Comment: @StackThis Fixed some minor bug in Mobile Firefox. Edited my jQuery code.

Comment: Hey Roko, thanks again for this.. It works wonders on firefox and chrome, which is really great.. One question though, on Safari (iOS too) the content doesn't scroll and the footer seems to stick to the bottom of the content, rendering it inaccessible.. Any suggestions on how to remedy this?

Comment: Posted a dedicated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712743/css-set-height-header-footer-with-dynamic-content-not-working-on-osxsafari-i thanks again

Comment: Opened a bounty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712743/css-set-height-header-footer-with-dynamic-content-not-working-on-osxsafari-i .. would really appreciate any ideas, thanks