# CSS - Set height header/footer, with dynamic content..not working on osXsafari/iOSsafari? (jsBin)

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser, responsive-design

[I have this great solution from @RokoC.Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215541/css-relative-header-and-sticky-footer-dynamic-content-unknown-height-all-in), but it only works on chrome & firefox..on safari, the content section does not scroll and the footer seems to stick to the bottom of the content, rendering it inaccessible..

Is there any way to remedy this for Safari/iOSsafari? ..or an alt solution that's cross-browser compatible?

http://jsbin.com/negin/9/edit

HTML:

```
<div id="view">
  <div id="appear"> Content that appears </div>
  <div id="header"> Header </div>
  <div id="content"> <h1>Content</h1> <p>Lorem ipsum...</p> </div>
  <div id="footer"> Footer </div>
</div>
```

CSS (using [calc for dynamic seems supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc), but maybe this is the issue?):

```
#view {
  overflow: hidden;           /* NO SCROLLBARS */
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000;
  color:#fff;

  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 100vh;
}
#appear{
  display:none;
}
#header,
#footer {
  height: 44px;               /* note this */
  background-color: #555;
}
#content {
  overflow-y: scroll;         /* SCROLLBARS !!!*/
  height: calc(100% - 88px);  /* 44+44 = 88px */
}
```

jQuery (setting a fixed height to header and to Footer, using calc(100% - 88px) for the scrollable content, and having the appear section slidedown from above thanks to calc):

```
$("#view").on("click", "#header", function () {
  var $appear = $('#appear');
  var io = this.io ^= 1; // Toggler

  $appear.show();               // Temporarily show
  var animH = $appear.height(); // Get height and
  if(io) $appear.hide();        // fast hide.
  $appear.slideToggle();        // Now do it with animation

  $('#content').animate({       // Animate content height
      height: (io?"-=":"+=")+animH
    },{
      step: function() {
        $(this).css("overflow-y", "scroll");
      },
      complete : function(){
        var h = 88 + (io?animH:0); // header+footer = 88px
        $(this).css({height: "calc(100% - "+ h +"px)"});
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Mobile Safari, at least, has very buggy support for `vh` (see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)). Have you tried using JavaScript to give `#view` an equivalent height?

Comment: @RyanMitchell thanks for isolating the issue!

Comment: also consider changing `height: 100vh;`  that should clear the code.

Comment: If you add -webkit-calc as well, does that do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RyanMitchell for isolating the issue, and recommending writing some javascript to determine the vh (viewport height) to set for the height of #view

Here's the working code, pulled from http://j.eremy.net/set-element-height-to-viewport/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('#view').css('height', windowHeight);
  }
  setHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/bivupuqa/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

Ok, go to https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill and download the script, than include the script in your `<head>`. After that run

```
window.viewportUnitsBuggyfill.init(true);
```

And voila! automagically it works!

link to jsbin: http://jsbin.com/yovoy/1/edit